# Is there way to check how many times user pressed key down (F9)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button, key

By pressing F9 I am sending document to a printer, is there way to detect how many times user clicked that Key,
because I want to allow only one print by one `Key Down`, I know there is MouseButtonEventArgs.ClickCount Property
for Buttons in C#, so I might do simply ;

```
if (e.ClickCount == 1)
{
    // Single Click occurred.Do something

}
```

but is there something for Key Downs?

So my question is : 
How could I limit user to press it only once at a time, beacause I dont want to have situation when user is 
spamming F9 and sending a lot documents to a printer..
Or I could create by own `button event handler` and move my logic there,
and on key down I could call that `button event click` method and inside I could count clicks?

Comment: Why not count the KeyDowns yourself? And perhaps introduce a TimeSpan and only deal with one KeyDown per,let's say, every 10 seconds?

Comment: Make some counter variable within time elapse event

Comment: @rbm how could I introduce time span to deal with one KeyDown per xx seconds? can you provide me an example please..

Comment: If you're going to limit the user to only one press at a time, there's no need to count.  Just create an `internal static` "IsPrinting" `Boolean` variable, then toggle it to `true` in the `KeyDown` event if the key is F9.  Handle the "done printing"-style event and toggle your "IsPrinting" variable back to `false`.   Put in a check to make sure that `IsPrinting == false ` before the print code executes and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I limit user to press it only once at a time, beacause I dont want to have situation when user is spamming F9 and sending a lot documents to a printer

You need to define what "a time" actually means, i.e. if you want the user to be able to click once per second or once per two seconds or whatever.

You could to this by defining a `TimeSpan` field and compare the difference between the current time and the time of the last key press to the value of this one, e.g.:

```
readonly static TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); //allow printing once per (1) second
DateTime lastKeyPress;
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F9 && DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastKeyPress) >= ts)
    {
        //print...
    }
    lastKeyPress = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: this works, and what about that If I put this in try catch finally and on finally I could remove items  from list which is being send to printer, and on the beggining of Key.Down I could check if(PrintList.Count>0){//Print}? What about that, that might work too?

Comment: I guess, provided that the PrintList is defined at class level and not inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to count numbers of times by yourself.

Because you want to know that button has been pressed once, 
you don't have to save it with a `int` you can you a simple `bool`.

Declaration:

`private static bool alreadyPrint = false;`

In keyDown event:

`alreadyPrint = true;`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do something nontrivial with events you should look into [Reactive Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/). Here is an intro to Rx: [link](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html).

With Rx, you will be able to treat your events as data streams. For example, if you have an `Observable` into which you feed your F9 events and you want to print a document only if F9 was pressed once in last 400 ms you can do something like this:

```
F9Observable.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400))
            .Do(_ => Print())
```

([about Throttle method](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Throttle))

If someone will press F9 to often a document will not be printed until they stop.